# discord.py discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions error

Tags: python, discord.py

I am to give role to some users when they react but it says

```
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

And the bot have administrator permissions

Here is my code :

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    emoji = payload.emoji.name  
    canal = payload.channel_id  
    message = payload.message_id 

    python_role = get(bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).roles, name="python")
    member = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id).get_member(payload.user_id)

    if canal == 703637575566491731 and message == 703643218658459778 and emoji == "python":
        await membre.add_roles(python_role)
```

the error code :

```
   Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/tp's/bot discord/main.py", line 30, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await membre.add_roles(python_role)
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 221, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Role of the bot has to be higher than the one given to the user.

there is also a spelling mistake:`await membre.add_roles(python_role)`
membr/member

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the role of the bot is high on the role hierarchy.

This is a picture of where to put your bots role on the hierarchy

[image]